# Write simple functions inside screens in Flutter using BloC

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have been working on a Flutter application, using the BloC pattern. I have two functions that I don't know if I should write them in my BloC file. Here goes the code.

This is my BloC file code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:FlutterTWOHANDSAPPv2/Pets/model/createPetScreenProperties.dart';
import 'package:FlutterTWOHANDSAPPv2/bloc/jsonReader.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:generic_bloc_provider/generic_bloc_provider.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class PetsBloc implements Bloc {
  CreatePetScreenProperties properties;

  PetsBloc() {
    properties = CreatePetScreenProperties();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
  }

  getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

    PickedFile image = await picker.getImage(source: source);
    if (image != null) {
      File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          sourcePath: image.path,
          aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
          compressQuality: 100,
          maxWidth: 1000,
          maxHeight: 1000,
          compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
          androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            toolbarTitle: JsonReader.getTranslationString("CREATEPET_CROP"),
            statusBarColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ));
    } else {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my screen file

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:FlutterTWOHANDSAPPv2/Pets/bloc/petsBloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:generic_bloc_provider/generic_bloc_provider.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class CreateNewPetScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  PetsBloc bloc;
  bool inProcessOfSelectingImage() => bloc.properties.inProcessOfSelectingImage;
  File imageOfPet() => bloc.properties.image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bloc = BlocProvider.of(context);

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: selectPetPicture,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: 150,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(image: getImageOfPet()),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void selectPetPicture() {
    bloc.getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
  }

  ImageProvider<Object> getImageOfPet() {
    return imageOfPet() != null
        ? FileImage(imageOfPet())
        : AssetImage("heregoesadefaultimageasset");
  }
}
```

As you can see, in my screen, I have two functions at the very bottom, which do some very basic stuff, so I feel they don't fit in my BloC file. Should I write them there? Am I breaking the architecture if I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you have going on in your PetsBloc class that actually uses anything specific to the bloc pattern. From what I see you could remove that implementation and create the `PetsBloc` like a normal object and the functionality wouldn't change. That being said, assuming you had a full blown Bloc class setup with a `mapEventToState` method...proper Bloc architecture would be only firing events from your UI that then trigger a state.

```
bloc.add(EventThatTriggersState);
```

However [Cubits](https://medium.com/flutterando/cubit-a-simple-solution-for-app-state-management-in-flutter-66ab5279ef73) are great for simpler tasks and it would not be against intended architecture to have simple functions like that in a Cubit class.

Comment: I have been trying to understand what the BloC pattern is in reality, so its kinda hard for me, and after reading a lot more online, BloC isn't just the "logic", but in Flutter's case, the state management (which I don't really understand too since I'm a newbie). Thank you for your response! I'll take a deeper look.

Comment: No problem. Out of all the state management solutions Bloc is arguably the most tricky to wrap your head around. But also among the most powerful. If you want to really learn it, [The official docs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted) would be a good place to start. Just go through all the examples and follow along, it'll make sense eventually. The [ResoCoder tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y564ETOCog8) is also excellent.

Comment: That being said, if you're just starting out, you'd probably benefit from learning [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) first. They both will be easier to pick up. GetX to me is the fastest to get going as its the least amount boilerplate, and it's very powerful.

Comment: After reading 2 hours straight, I kinda understood now what BloC really is! Thank you for your help